# C++ Multi-thread runtime error: abort() has been called

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector

I was writing a C++ program, from time n = 168 to 0, to compute backward W(t) based on values W(t+1). W(t) is a 3D modified vector with negative index. I choose to run k-multi thread to fill-in value in Wt[k][i][j]. Single thread version works fine but when running on multi thread it failed with report_runtime_error: "abort() has been called." (from the Main thread). I tried to check the Thread window but not much clue found. Can anyone help/guide me on how to debug?

(i) How can I be told which worker thread at which step is causing the error?

(ii) Should I put some breakpoint in the debug mode?

```
// class ForwardShootingGrid was created as a modified 3D vector to cater negative index 
ForwardShootingGrid Wt;
ForwardShootingGrid Wtp1;

// as a worker thread 
void ComputeGridValue_LayerK(int n, int i_max, int j_max, int k) {
    ......
    for (int i = -i_max; i <= i_max; i++) {
        for (int j = -j_max; j <= j_max; j++) {
            ......
            x = ......    // x depends on value from ForwardShootingGrid Wtp1
            Wt.AssignGridValue(k, i, j, x);    // to input value=x into Wt[k][i][j]
            ......
        }
    }
}

// as a Main thread
int main(int, char*[]) {
    for (int n = n_max - 1; n >= 0; n--) {    // n is somehow like the time index
        i_max = n;
        j_max = n;
        k_max = ...

        // Everytime copy ForwardShootingGrid Wt to Wtp1, and then recompute Wt which is based on value from Wtp1  
        Wtp1 = Wt;
        // resize Wt
        Wt.ResizeGrid(0, k_max, -i_max, i_max, -j_max, j_max);

        for (int k = 0; k <= k_max; k++) {
            oThreads[k] = std::thread(ComputeGridValue_LayerK, n, i_max, j_max, k);
        }
        for (int k = 0; k <= k_max; k++) {
            oThreads[k].join();
        }
}
```

Comment: Please only use the Visual Studio tag for questions about the tool itself (not for general programming questions).

Comment: Is `AssignGridValue` thread-safe? Is `oThreads` at least `k + 1` elements large? What is the callstack when `abort` is called?

Comment: @Cameron: Thanks for your reply. (i) But I tried using vector in simular coding and it works fine (when multiple thread is updating the same vector). (ii) Call stack seems to be suggesting Main thread is calling the Abort() error. (iii) How can I told which worker thread is causing the breakpoint? Should I put some breakpoint in the debug mode?